# Is there a way to dynamically determine the number of cuda streams?

Tags: cuda

Is there a way to determine the number of cuda streams during program execution rather than at compiling? Just like using the "new" command. (The "stream" refers to a block of codes, not threads)

Edit 1

(In response of last comment) Say

```
for(int i = 0; i < nstreams; ++i)

    (Some serial code here, not related to kernel or cuda memory copy);

    someKernel<<<xx, yy, 0, stream[i]>>>(param list);

end
```

Without the serial code, the kernels should execute in parallel, if my understanding is correct?

But will the kernel execute concurrently, given the serial code can be parallelized by i (i.e. can be parallelized in OpenMP fashion, if taken out). Will it affect the concurrency?

Comment: I just tried 'malloc' command which returns a 'cudaStream_t' pointer. The code can compile, but feels a little weird. Will test to see whether this runs correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the number of streams can be determined at runtime.

```
int num_streams;
// ... set num_streams at runtime
cudaStream_t streams[num_streams];
for (int i = 0; i < num_streams; i++)
  cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[i]));
```

The following constructs also work:

```
int num_streams;
// ... set num_streams
cudaStream_t *streams = (cudaStream_t *)malloc(num_streams*sizeof(cudaStream_t));
for (int i = 0; i < num_streams; i++)
  cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[i]));
```

or:

```
int num_streams;
// ... set num_streams
cudaStream_t *streams = new cudaStream_t[num_streams];
for (int i = 0; i < num_streams; i++)
  cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[i]));
```

Comment: But the `streams` here is an array, isn't it? I think the number of elements must be specified at compile time? Tried your code but it won't compile unless using some code like `const int num_streams = 2`;

Comment: no, the number of elements don't need to be specified at compile time.  The above examples compile properly for me without `const`

Comment: Well, checked and array can be dynamic size in C99.. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if my understanding is correct, the streams inside the for loop will be executed in parallel after compilation (if there is enough resource). However, if I add some serial code in the loop, will that affect the parallelism? Say some operation on the loop variable `i`.

Comment: Given that the serial codes only depend on `i`, i.e. the whole for loop is still parallel by semantics.

Comment: The for loop is not parallel.  This is just setup code.  After you create the streams, then you use them elsewhere in your code.  And unless stated explicitly, I'm assuming C++.  You mention `new` in your question, which is C++, not C.